# Why is findvalue incredibly slow (LibXML)

Tags: xml, perl

There are 30,000 sets of data in array/item.
On my work server, (A) takes 30 minutes and (B) takes 5 seconds.
On my home computer, (A) and (B) both take 5 seconds.

Why is (A) so slow on my work server?

```
===========================================
                    foreach my $node2 ($node1->findnodes('array/item')){

= APPROACH (A) ============================
                        $xml_index = $node2->findvalue('index');
                        $xml_value = $node2->findvalue('value');

= APPROACH (B) ============================
                        foreach my $node3 ($node2->childNodes){
                            if($node3->nodeType() == XML_ELEMENT_NODE){
                                if($node3->getName() eq "index"){
                                    $xml_index=$node3->to_literal();
                                }
                                if($node3->getName() eq "value"){   
                                    $xml_value=$node3->to_literal();
                                }
                            }
                        }
===========================================
```

And if you need to see the whole thing -

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use File::Basename;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

my $filebase; my $file; my $int; my $boolDone; my $str;
my $line; my $whole; my $name; my $inputfilename;my $inputfolder;my $outputfile; my $doc; my $dt;my $dt1;my $dt2;my $dto_type;
my $xml_index; my $xml_value;

# INPUT
$inputfolder = ".";
opendir (DIR, $inputfolder) or die $!;

while ($inputfilename = readdir(DIR)){
    # one loop per file
    next if $inputfilename eq '.';
    next if $inputfilename eq '..';

    if(substr($inputfilename,-4) eq ".dto"){
        $doc = $parser->parse_file($inputfolder."/".$inputfilename);
        $dto_type = $doc->findvalue('object/class');

        if($dto_type eq "sshp.escs.cecs.mips.data.MipsPeerStatusObject_TImpl"){
            print "Importing File: ".$inputfilename."\n";

            #OUTPUT
            $outputfile = &ExtractFilenameNoExt($inputfilename);
            $outputfile = $outputfile.".csv";
            open(my $fh, '>', $outputfile) or die "Error '$outputfile' $!";

            #csv file headers
            $line = "index,"."value";
            print $fh $line."\n";

            $int = 1;
            foreach my $node1 ($doc->findnodes('object/field/object/field/object/field/object/field')){
                if($node1->findvalue('name') eq "statusData"){
                    foreach my $node2 ($node1->findnodes('array/item')){

#                       $xml_index = $node2->findvalue('index');
#                       $xml_value = $node2->findvalue('value');

                        foreach my $node3 ($node2->childNodes){
                            if($node3->nodeType() == XML_ELEMENT_NODE){
                                if($node3->getName() eq "index"){
                                    $xml_index=$node3->to_literal();
                                }
                                if($node3->getName() eq "value"){   
                                    $xml_value=$node3->to_literal();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $line = $xml_index.",".$xml_value;
                        print $fh $line."\n";
                        $xml_index = "";
                        $xml_value = "";

                        if($int %10000 == 0){
                            print $int."\n";
                        }
                        $int++;
                    }
                }
            }
            close $fh;
        }
    }
}

my $elapsed_seconds = time - $^T;
print "duration: ".$elapsed_seconds." seconds";

sub ExtractFilenameNoExt(){
    my ($file) = @_;
    $file = basename($file);
    return substr($file,0,(length($file)-length(ExtractExt($file))-1));
}
sub ExtractExt{
    my ($file) = @_;
    return substr($file, rindex($file, '.') + 1);
}
```

And if you need to see a sample of the xml -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<object>
  <field>
    <object>
      <field>
        <object>
          <field>
            <object>
              <field>
                <name>statusData</name>
                <class>[B</class>
                <array>
                  <class>[B</class>
                  <size>30152</size>
                  <item>
                    <class>java.lang.Byte</class>
                    <index>0</index>
                    <value>0</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <class>java.lang.Byte</class>
                    <index>1</index>
                    <value>0</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <class>java.lang.Byte</class>
                    <index>30150</index>
                    <value>-63</value>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <class>java.lang.Byte</class>
                    <index>30151</index>
                    <value>-24</value>
                  </item>
                </array>
              </field>
            </object>
          </field>
        </object>
      </field>
    </object>
  </field>
</object>
```

Comment: Usually problems with speed of XML parsing are related to incorrect choicing  XML parser type (DOM based or event based). But in your situation it seems that size of xml file is not too huge to affect performance. Also try to examine what amount of memory is used by your script.

Comment: There's no doubt about it, the childNodes approach is faster than the findValue approach, by a factor of 15 times. I have another xml file with 30,000 rows of 30 fields each, and it took 15 seconds using childNodes, and 3.7 minutes using findValue.

Comment: Check this out.
(1) restart windows PC.  (2) run perl script using strawberry perl. duration = 186 seconds.  (3) run perl script using strawberry perl again. duration = 26 seconds. (4) restart windows pc. (5) run perl script using strawberry perl. (6) duration = 186 seconds.  So the lesson learned here is that xml file memory caching plays a major role in how long it takes to run the script.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something more like:

```
use XML::Rules;

my @rules = (
  item => [
    'array' => sub {
      my $item = $_[1];
      print "index: $item->{index} value: $item->{value}\n";
    },
  ],
  'index,value' => 'content',
  _default => undef,
);

my $xr = XML::Rules->new(
  rules => \@rules,
);
$xr->parse($xml);
# or
$xr->parse_file($xml_file);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your approach A, I think the findvalue method creates a loop that reads internally all content.
What I would do is try to program something similar to the approach B

Comment: sounds like a reasonable explanation for the slowdown, but it surprises me, because in that inner-most FOREACH it should only be finding nodes inside one occurrence of an   'array/item'   element.

Comment: I looked a snippet code of the findvalue method and seems to be doing a lot of checks to match the search.